# Can I validates_uniqueness_of email in two models at once in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a model for a client, when I create a new client it creates a User with the client email. The same thing happens when I create an Affiliate. Can I use validates_uniqueness_of the email in both Client and user at the same time?

Or should I do something like, before save check if there is a User with the same email, and print an error?

I tried this, but it doesn't work

```
validate :uniqueness_of_user

  private

  def uniqueness_of_user
    @user = User.find_by_email(:email)
    if @user.present?
      errors.add(:email, "Bang!")
    end
  end
```

Edit:

This is the controller:

```
def create
    @affiliate = Affiliate.new(affiliate_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if verify_recaptcha(model: @affiliate) && @affiliate.save
        @user = User.create!(user_parameter)
        pplicationMailer.confirmation(@affiliate).deliver_now

        format.html {redirect_to :back, notice: 'Thanks for your submission, we will be in touch shortly. Check your email for your affiliate number and password.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @affiliate }
      else
        format.html { render :signup, layout: "sign-ups"  }
        format.json { render json: @affiliate.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: There is a validator for uniqueness. You don't need to write it yourself. Also if user can only be created through client, you don't need to enforce there too (it won't hurt anyway). validation will look like `validates :email, uniqueness: true`

Comment: If some users pre exist, or can be created differently than from the client. I suggest you check in the controller that a user don't have this email before creating the client (and still enforce uniqueness in both models). Also encapsulate the client and user creation into a `transaction` and do it in the same block. (In create action of clients controller for example)

Comment: That validates only inside client or affiliate. Both clients and affiliates create an user. My problem is that some affiliates will try to use the same email for a client and because the user already exists, the client will be saved but there will be an error because the user already exists. So before the user or affiliate is created I need to check if the user with that email exists

Comment: Ok users can be created two ways. Then check my second option. You have to check if email exists in users before creating. (Or you just don't: if you enforce uniqueness it will just fail and you can ask the visitor to submit another email). Just make sure you create both client/user in the same `transaction` block: if it fails to create user, the client will not be created.

Comment: I edited the question with the create action

Answer (score 0):

Check below code for a good article about this case, I copied the code but for full explanation check the article link :

```
# app/models/concerns/validate_identifier_uniqueness_across_models.rb
module ValidateIdentifierUniquenessAcrossModels
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  @@included_classes = []

  included do
    @@included_classes << self
    validate :identifier_unique_across_all_models
  end

  private

  def identifier_unique_across_all_models
    return if self.identifier.blank?
    @@included_classes.each do |klass|
      scope = klass.where(identifier: self.identifier)
      if self.persisted? && klass == self.class
        scope = scope.where('id != ?', self.id)
      end
      if scope.any?
        self.errors.add :identifier, 'is already taken'
        break
      end
    end
  end
end

# app/models/product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ValidateIdentifierUniquenessAcrossModels
end

# app/models/category.rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ValidateIdentifierUniquenessAcrossModels
end
```

**Reference:**
https://www.krautcomputing.com/blog/2015/03/29/rails-validate-uniqueness-across-models/

**UPDATE:**
**Solution 1** If data are saved at the same time, then the best thing is to include the data saved together in a Transaction as below:

```
  def create
    email_validity
    @affiliate = Affiliate.new(affiliate_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
        if verify_recaptcha(model: @affiliate) && @affiliate.save

      @user = User.create!(user_parameter)
      if @user.valid?
        ApplicationMailer.confirmation(@affiliate).deliver_now

        format.html {redirect_to :back, notice: 'Thanks for your submission, we will be in touch shortly. Check your email for your affiliate number and password.'}
        format.json {render :show, status: :created, location: @affiliate}
      else
        email_validity = false
        raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
      end
    else

      format.html {render :signup, layout: "sign-ups"}
      format.json {render json: @affiliate.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
    end
  end

  if email_validity == false
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to :back, notice: 'Sorry, email is in use!'}
      # you can add your json return as you like
    end
  end
end
```

end

**Reference:**
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Rollback.html

**Solution 2** before saving to affiliate or creating a user, check in both tables for email existence in your controller.

Comment: I tried changing the identifier to email, and  products/category to client/affiliate. But it doesn't validate. It still creates the affiliate and gives me a page error saying that the user with that email already exists because I have a validation on users too.

Comment: @Allan Can you show the code where you save both data together ?

Comment: Using your code I still got an error, but then i changed to ` if User.find_by_email(user_params[:email]).nil?   @user = User.create!(user_parameter) ` Now I get the rollback transaction and the affiliate doesn't save. but the notice doesn't show and I get this in the console: `No template found for AffiliatesController#create, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 3022ms (ActiveRecord: 4.0ms)
`

Comment: I have updated the answer, once rollback transaction is raised, it will go out the block. I have added a flag `email_validity` to check and return correct response.

Comment: Why didn't you try to check in both tables for email uniqueness before you create in anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I would have preferred to save the email_address in a different table. for example: address

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord

   belongs_to :affilat
   belongs_to :client

   validates :email,
              presence: true 
              uniqueness: true
end
```

and use nested form to save date here.